# I am developing one application in which i want to add image on another image where user touch.please help me

Tags: android

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
          {
              if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
              {
                  int x = (int) event.getX() ;
                  int y = (int) event.getY();
                  System.out.println("xxx");
                release=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //Assuming you use a RelativeLayout

                  ImageView iv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

                  System.out.println("YYYY");
                  lp.setMargins(x,y,0,0);

                  System.out.println("aaaa");
                 iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
                  System.out.println("bbbbb");
                  iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pain_icon));
                  System.out.println("ccccc");


       ((ViewGroup)v).addView(release);


              }

        return true;

          }
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: my image is not displaing.i m having error on line ((ViewGroup)v).addView(release);

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post the logcat output you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added the dynamicallly created view to ur parent. first declare ur parent and add this iv (imageview in ur code) to the parent using relativeLayout.addView(iv);

Comment: replace the "release" image view and try it with iv.

Comment: k just declare the parent layout and initialize and replace the ((ViewGroup)v) with that parent layout variable and set lauout params for the imageview as wrap content and try

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing here since you din't post the error.

R.id.imageView2 most likely has a parent and you are trying to add it to another viewgroup. thats whats causing the  error. you need to create a new instance of ImageView then add it to your view group

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
im.setImageResource(R.drawable.nameofimage);

((ViewGroup)v).addView(im);
```